# Change keyboard layout in Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard, debian, keyboard-layout

could someone remind me which package do I need to reconfigure to change the default console keyboard layout in Debian?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

isn't it the console-data?

As I can remember, you should `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-data`